# Как использовать обобщенное сопоставление с образцом для любых "причудливых" ("fancy") типов?

Tags: haskell, сопоставление-с-образцом

Например, я пишу функцию, для типа `Maybe`, так, что она принимает "причудливое" значение `Maybe` и возвращает инкриментированное "простое" значение:

```
test1 :: Num a => Maybe a -> a
test1 (Just a) = a + 1

{-
*Main> test1 (Just 3)
4
-}
```

Ок, работает. В качестве паттерна использовали выражение `(Just a)`.

Теперь в качестве "придудливого" значения используем список с тем же смыслом:

```
test2 :: Num a => [a] -> a
test2 [a] = a + 1
{-
*Main> test2 [3]
4
-}
```

Получилось. В качестве паттерна использовали `[a]`, то есть "простое" значение, обернутое в список.

Теперь я хочу создать функцию типа:

```
test3 :: Num a => (i a) -> a
```

Как мне теперь указать "обобщенный" паттерн, имеющий смысл "возьми  причудливое значения и возврати инкремент обернутого в него простого значения", что то типа (код содержит синтаксическую ошибку):

```
test3 :: Num a => (i a) -> a
test3 (i y) = y + 1
-- Parse error in pattern: i
```

Возможно ли в принципе использовать в Haskell такого рода обобщение в сопоставлении с образцом? (Не обязательно указанным мной способом) Например, я хочу использовать в функции класса типа, но пока вынужден описывать функцию в каждой инстанции класса, в классе только объявление типа:

```
class Test i where
    testInc :: Num a => (i a) -> a

instance Test Maybe where
    testInc Nothing = 0
    testInc (Just x) = x + 1

{-
*Main> testInc $ Just 3
4
*Main> testInc Nothing
0
-}

instance Test [] where
    testInc [] = 0
    testInc [a] = a + 1

{-
*Main> testInc [3]
4
*Main> testInc []
0
-}
```

Как мне сразу описать функцию с этим смыслом в классе `Test`? Возможно ли это?

Comment: Теперь (когда я описал вопрос) я вижу, что в таком виде, как у меня - невозможно, так как откуда функция "знает" какой именно конструктор "причудливого" значения следует использовать (в принципе, их может быть несколько)? Но может есть более хитрый способ или практика, о которой я не знаю - описать логику функции для "причудливых" значений только один раз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Универсального решения для произвольного конструктора нет, и классы типов - это правильный выход. Более того, в библиотеке уже есть походящий класс типов `Foldable`

```hs
import Data.Foldable (toList)

test3 :: (Num a, Foldable f) => f a -> a
test3 v = sum v + 1

testInc :: (Num a, Foldable f) => f a -> a
testInc v = case toList v of
  []  -> 0
  [x] -> x + 1
```

Для `Maybe` и `[]` уже реализованы представители `Foldable`

```hs
*Main> test3 (Just 3)
4
*Main> test3 [3]
4
*Main> test3 []
1
*Main> testInc $ Just 3
4
*Main> testInc Nothing
0
*Main> testInc [3]
4
*Main> testInc []
0
```

Для остальных типов можно объявить представителей в том числе автоматически.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data MyType1 a = MyData1 a deriving (Show, Foldable)
data MyType2 a = MyData2 a a deriving (Show, Foldable)
data MyType3 a = Empty | Some a deriving (Show, Foldable)
data MyType4 a = Nil | Cons a (MyType4 a) deriving (Show, Foldable)
```

В вашем распоряжении все члены класса типов `Foldable` и прочие функции из модуля `Data.Foldable`: `all`, `find`, `toList` и т.д.

```hs
*Main> length (Cons 1 $ Cons 2 $ Cons 3 $ Nil)
3
*Main> toList (Cons 1 $ Cons 2 $ Cons 3 $ Nil)
[1,2,3]
```

> Например, я хочу использовать в функции класса типа, но пока вынужден описывать функцию в каждой инстанции класса

Так оно обычно и делается

> Как мне сразу описать функцию с этим смыслом в классе Test? Возможно ли это?

Ну логику инкремента, которая будет одинаковой для всех типов, можно описать в классе. Логику извлечения придется оставить в инстансе.

```hs
class Test i where
  testGet :: i a -> Maybe a
  testInc :: Num a => i a -> a
  testInc v = maybe 0 (+ 1) (testGet v)

instance Test Maybe where
  testGet = id

instance Test [] where
  testGet [x] = Just x
  testGet []  = Nothing
```

Но лучше сделать `testInc` внешней функцией, как раз по причине того, что меняться от типа к типу она не будет.

```hs
class Test i where
  testGet :: i a -> Maybe a

testInc :: (Num a, Test i) => i a -> a
testInc v = maybe 0 (+ 1) (testGet v)
```

Comment: Великолепный ответ! Спасибо!